# ES6 Module Imports into multiple JS files

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

I'm new to using imports/exports with ES6. I am currently messing around with PixiJs, webpack, and babel. I was wondering if I need to import my pixijs script into each script I would use it. Do I need to do`import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js` in every single JS file that would use it, or does it only need to be imported once? I have tried looking the answer up, but I can't seem to think of a good way to word it that results in any kind of relevant answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You only need to import it in those files which require access to `PIXI`. Other js files that don't create new applications/sprites/whatever in Pixi do not need to have it imported.

Comment: Gotcha, but if I end up needing to create new Sprites or what every I would need to then. Got it, thank you!